# How to align poetry with reference

Tags: css

Search in Stack Overflow helped me to get an answer for aligning poetry justified for all and the last line. with the following CSS code, it works perfectly aligning the last glyph. Those who may not know, single and double vertical lines at the end of the line in Sanskrit is equivalent to full stop in English. In Sanskrit poetry, the single and double lines (full stops) also signify how they are recited and therefore alignment of these is very crucial for a reader.

This is the CSS code that helps me to align the Sanskrit poetry lines. (Using Divi Code modules).

```
.et_pb_code {
    font-family: Sanskrit;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3C268C;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.et_pb_code:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

[Here is the example of the poetry in Sanskrit and giving the reference in small sized but different font.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIcLl.png)

The question is: How do I align the last reference line to the poetry to the right side of the poem and not to the far right of the page as shown by the first image?

I would be very pleased if there is a way through CSS to right align the reference where the poetry lines end.

[I hope to achieve the results as per the picture link but haven't been able to do so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSNme.png)

Note: I formatted the desired outcome (second picture) in Word 2016 using textbox to right align the reference line. I, then, tried to export as filtered HTML to see how Word would handle this. But it saved the text box as image and that is not what I want. There must be some CSS solution that I am looking for tips.

Comment: Could you provide also your HTML? Or create jsbin.com example of your implementation?

Comment: Hi - I never used jsbin.com before but tried. This is at https://jsbin.com/ludomed/edit?html,css

Comment: @Anarion - But, please see that the output is what I want but this is not representative since content width is same. If you look at the actual example http://r.zinox.com, you will see that the last line is right justified to the actual content width.

Comment: But what I see in your jsbin and on this site is the same. The only difference is that in this example blue text is in fact not `text-align: justify;`. It is left aligned and won't take the whole line width as you do. Just same text width. So what's wrong and what result you actually want? Please describe it more clear.